# tkinter text widget: Setting the insertion curser

Tags: python, autocomplete, tkinter

I want to create automcomplete feature in a tkinter text widget. When the autocomplete finds a possible word, it deletes the user part-of-word, then insert the complete word:

```
#if some matched words are found
if self._hits != []:

   #delete the part written by the user
   self.text.delete("%s+1c" % Space1Index,INSERT)

   #Inser the complete word
   self.text.insert("%s+1c" % Space1Index,self._hits[self._hit_index])
```

Then I will tag the text added by the autocomplete to have a different look than the user input. For ex, if the user wrote `te`, autocomplete will write the complete word `test`. `te` will be with normal font, and `st` will be wrote in another color and waits for the user to confirm the selected word by the computer.

My question is, after inserting the word `test` and properly highlighting it, how can I move the INSERT position again after `te`?

I hope I could clarify my question enough, please let me know if more explanation is needed.

Comment: You might want to change the title of your question. It mentions autocomplete, but the actual question is about setting the insertion cursor.

Comment: Can you show us the complete code for it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the insertion cursor, set the "insert" mark to wherever you want:

```
self.text.mark_set("insert", "%s+1c" % ...)
```

-or-

```
self.text.mark_set(INSERT, "%s+1c" % ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the position of the insert mark before your autocompletion changes and reset the mark to the saved position after:

```
old_pos = self.text.index("insert")
# make autocompletion changes
self.text.mark_set("insert", old_pos)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any good references about text widget .. I found some online but without enough examples or explanation.

Comment: I think you mean self.text.mark_set(`"insert"`, old_pos)

Comment: Yes, I've modified my answer. For references, there is http://www.tkdocs.com. Very good, but not all widget are covered (yet). The ultimate doc is http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm It is for tcl but functions are ported almost identically in tkinter.